# Why are VS 2015 menu right aligned?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My menus started to be right-aligned one day. What can be broken?

[image]

Comment: How close is the tools menu to the right edge of your screen?

Comment: It wasn't the problem with being to close to the edge. Anyway, the answer below worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm very glad this question was asked. I hadn't a clue that this was caused by my pen!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've had this happen...

This happens when Windows thinks you are using a pen-controlled device with your right hand.

You can change the orientation in the Tablet PC Settings or Pen & Touch Settings control panel, which you can open easily (according to https://www.askvg.com/how-to-change-menu-position-from-left-to-right-in-windows-vista/) by running (as in Windows > Run, or Win+R)

`explorer shell:::{80F3F1D5-FECA-45F3-BC32-752C152E456E}`

and changing the Handedness value.

Comment: This still works in Visual Studio 2019 under Windows 10, when all menus are suddenly on the left site.